# do the files opened using $.post and $.get register as open files on linux server?

Tags: php, ajax, unix, setinterval

I have recently updated my site with the use of ajax calls to improve the end-user experience. Some calls are set to poll the db repeadedly, others are called at to alter the database upon user interaction ie. completing a task or cancelling a cart item.

Now I am getting server errors resulting from reaching my servers open file limit.

Here is an example of the sort of code I am using: (credit goes to every tutorial found on google...)

```
function checkForNewData() {   
   $.get('checkForNewData.php',false,function(data){      
      if(data.length){      
          $('#newData').html(data);
        } 
   }); 
}

$(function(){  
   checkForNewData();  
     setInterval('checkForNewData()',10000); 
});
```

I realize that by using "setInterval('checkForNewData()',10000);" that this means that file is loaded every 10000ms for every user that has this page open.

Here are my questions regarding my ignorance of ajax:

1. Does a unix server record each ajax call (of this manor) as a page load or open file?
2. If the page loads behind the scenes, do I have to close it?
3. Is there a better way to keep a site up-to-date than the repetitiously polling of my db.

Thanks for your time and assistants.

Comment: Another thing to do is to make sure that the tab with your page actually has focus and if not, maybe poll the server once every few minutes instead of every 10 seconds.

Comment: Does your `.php` have a `usleep()` or `sleep()` being called?

Comment: I am not using unsleep() or sleep(). the reoccurring calls are mainly involving navigation. ie in real(ish) time adding a (1) or (2) beside the messages button to alert you on new incoming messages.

Answer (score 0):

**Does a unix server record each ajax call (of this manor) as a page load or open file?**

Every-time a php file is run, it is logged. Executed PHP of any manner is recorded. That's why you can see errors in your error log if anything goes wrong during AJAX calls.

**If the page loads behind the scenes, do I have to close it?**

Which page? "checkForNewData.php"? No you don't. The AJAX call waits for the script to execute  & finish *and than* gets the response.

**Is there a better way to keep a site up-to-date than the repetitiously polling of my db?**

Yes, there is. I would:

**On the server**

- Use cache (maybe APC cache)
- Run a DB check once every minute/ two minutes/ five minutes only
- Store/ Update the results in an XML file

**On the client**

- Get the timestamp of the most recent update on client-side page load
- Get AJAX to check the timestamp (stored in the XML) of the last update
- If timestamp of the AJAX response differs from the first-load timestamp, get new HTML from the XML file

Use AJAX headers or AJAX post-data to request a specific function (like asking for timestamp update vs getting HTML data).

Remember to use the correct flags for json_encode.

```
print_r(json_encode($html,JSON_HEX_QUOT|JSON_HEX_TAG|JSON_HEX_AMP|JSON_HEX_APOS));
```

Also remember to zip the data.

```
ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
```

It is a best practice to have as fewer DB calls as possible.

Comment: thanks for your responses. I don't understand your your better practice calls the DB less times. if you are calling the db every minute to update an xml file, then calling the xml file too, would that not be more calls than ajaxing the db right from your page, and if data is new then load to page?

Comment: Consider this. You query your DB and store the result in an XML file _once every minute_. Suppose, you have 10 people visiting your site, you check the XML 10 times and not the DB. The DB is queried once every minute despite the number of hits on a webpage.

Comment: Again, you create a new PHP to handle the DB-to-XML part. That has nothing to do with AJAX calls. It just updates the XML every minute. There is a second PHP files which responds to AJAX calls and checks the XML file.

Comment: well that's an interesting thought. would you still handle it this way even though the data will not be similar across all users? would you create a unique xml file for each active user?

Comment: Yeah I would. My first task would be to get it right and test it with a small number of users. If it works well with 10 users, it will work well with 1000 or 10,000. Also, at any given time there would be only a part of your total user-base.

Comment: I appreciate your input. I'll be coding and testing until morning now... Thank you.